# what is the correct way to calculate the "double's range"?

Tags: double, double-precision, ieee

In 64 bits platform, the double's range are following:

```
-2.22507e-308 ~ +2.22507e-308
-1.79769e+308 ~ +1.79769e+308
```

and I followed the [IEEE754](http://www.programering.com/a/MDO5gjMwATQ.html) standard and tried to calculate the double's range by following equation,

```
x = (-1)^s * (1+fraction) * 2^(exponent-bias)
```

So I tried to calculate in 64 bits platform, but I am not sure the following whether it is right?

Since the bias is 1024, the max value of double can be calculated by following:

```
(1-2^-52) * 2^(2^11 - 1024) = 2.22507e-308
```

It seems right...

but when I calculate the min value of double by the same way

```
(1-2^-52) * 2^-(1024-1)) = 1.1125369292536007e-308, 
1024 -1 (minus 1 is for zero bit?))
```

the result is not correct... so I wonder what is correct way to calculate double's range by hand.

Thank in advance.

Comment: sorry, I have changed the tag...

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the lowest positive normal number, or the lowest positive subnormal?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yes..but I found the answer from wiki ...(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Good. Remember you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 3):

[Max](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) (substitute any sensible type):

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::max()
```

[Min](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest) (called "lowest" in C++11 because `min` meant something else, see comments):

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP was after, but "how do you actually go about calculating that value.

Comment: Sorry, maybe you misunderstand my question, my question is how to calculate it by hand instead of using code to show the max and min value...

Comment: @RyanLiu: if you didn't want C++ code, you should not have tagged your question C++.

Comment: @JohnZwinck sorry, I have removed it